# TextArea() - handling text content as list of words

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I like to have access to items/list of words in TextArea, like Word(2). Is there native support for that in TextArea() or some good List object to be used?

E.g.

```
 1stword = TextArea.TextAsList(1)
 2ndword = TextArea.TextAsList(2)
```

Since there is already .htmltext, is there some HTML object that could be used to make such a list easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Just get the text in there and use a String.Split.

Besides, if there were such a method, it would also do the split.

Comment: I agree, just split the string by spaces, and iterate one at a time.